# Optimization Problem - Rectangle inscribed in a circumference and smallest angular coefficient of a tangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been using a textbook to solve some Optimization problems and these two got my attention. The first one has no answer, just want to double check, and the second one is possibly wrong:

> What is the rectangle with maximum area that can be inscribed in a
>   circumference of radius $10 \ cm$?

For this one I got $5 \sqrt 2 \ cm$ for both height and width, not sure if its correct.

Second problem:

> What is the smallest angular coefficient of the tangent line of the
>   function
>
> $$y = (1+x^2)^{-1}$$
>
> in all its Domain?

For this one there are four options, but the one I got is different (hopefully the textbook is wrong)

> $$a) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , - \frac{3}{4}\right)$$
>
> $$b) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , - \frac{3}{2}\right)$$
>
> $$c) \left( - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \frac{3}{4}\right)$$
>
> $$d) \left( - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \frac{3}{2}\right)$$

My answer: $\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} , \frac{3}{4}\right)$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Angular coefficient* is (in mathematical English) a relatively uncommon term for the **slope** of the tangent line. Here, from the shape of the proposed answers, they seem to be using it to mean the point of tangency.

I agree that the minimum slope is at the point in the first quadrant with $x$-coordinate $1/\sqrt{3}$.

Your numerical answer to the first problem is also correct.

Comment: yes I meant slope, but wasn't very precise on translating from my language. Do you agree also that the point has y coordinate 3/4?

Comment: Sure, that's just substitution.

Comment: Ok, just checking. I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: are you a college professor? Where do you teach?

Comment: Yes, I am a Faculty member in a university math department.

Comment: that is great, congratulations for that achievement. Best Regards.